# Wheatstone bridge imbalance voltage calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis, wheatstone-bridge

I have a simple force measuring circuit which consists of a strain gauge SG1 and an amplifier with a Wheatstone bridge.

The variable resistor RV1 is set to 200 Ω. If the strain gauge is fully deflected, the circuit gives an output of 50 mV.

How would I go about calculating the imbalance voltage at the bridge?

I found the voltage that goes into the op-amp's pin3:

$$R_{FSR}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{1320}+\dfrac{1}{1320}}=660\ \Omega$$

$$V=\dfrac{680}{680+660}\cdot9=4.57\ \mathrm{V}$$

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking here and an even harder time figuring out why you have the op-amp wired that way. It should be like this https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=KBj%2b2iO5&id=BFAEE081236B4F36C6C35EAA2C1A11AD7AA2BDA1&thid=OIP.KBj-2iO50oZ5JHDKcXpagAEsD9&q=Wheatstone+Bridge+Amplifier&simid=608014079389075379&selectedIndex=105&ajaxhist=0

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the circuit.

Comment: Sure.. its fine till you hook any significant load on the output..

Comment: The Supply sensitivity is too high and you need a differential Amp on the output, when you should have it here.  Change all 1k2 to 120 and add an LDO for 15mA into 120 Ohms or 1.8V then use a rail to rail Op Amp with >10K load using Trevor's link. You should get 500mV then full scale then and less CM error and gain error.

Comment: Your gain is ~200 so the full scale input is 250uV making it very prone to noise and errors.  So there are a few things wrong

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it like this?
[image]

All your calculations are much easier this way and it's "kind of linear".